# type dependence of 'backward ' in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

```py
x = torch.ones(1, requires_grad=True)
print(x)
y = x + 2.
print(y)
y.backward()
print(x.grad)
```

-->result>>>>>

```py
tensor([1.], requires_grad=True)
tensor([3.], grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
tensor([1.])
```

Here is no problem. However, if I change the type, I get

```py
x = torch.ones(1, requires_grad=True)
x = x.double()
print(x)
y = x + 2.
y = y.double()
print(y)
y.backward()
print(x.grad)
```

-->result>>>>>

```py
tensor([1.], dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<CopyBackwards>)
tensor([3.], dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
None

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/tensor.py:746: UserWarning: The .grad attribute of a Tensor that is not a leaf Tensor is being accessed. Its .grad attribute won't be populated during autograd.backward(). If you indeed want the gradient for a non-leaf Tensor, use .retain_grad() on the non-leaf Tensor. If you access the non-leaf Tensor by mistake, make sure you access the leaf Tensor instead. See github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/30531 for more informations.
  warnings.warn("The .grad attribute of a Tensor that is not a leaf Tensor is being accessed. Its .grad "
```

=============================

What is the difference? Is there any restriction of 'type' on 'backward'?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the wrong tensor ;)

By calling `x = x.double()` you create a new tensor, so when you call `x.grad` later on, you call it on the `double()` version of `x`, which isn't your original `x` anymore.

Comment: Yeah, but I think then new x.grad should come out, and that should be same with the x.grad on the first code.  If there any restriction of dtype when I use backward?

Comment: The dtype does matter once you execute on GPU, apart from that, a backward computation follows the rules of any other computation for that matter. Do x_1 = x.double() and then later x.grad and it will work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
The .grad attribute of a Tensor that is not a leaf Tensor is being accessed.
```

means that you are accessing the `.grad` field of a Tensor for which PyTorch will never populate the `.grad` field. Note that, leaf Tensors will have their `.grad` field populated. So if this warning happens, it means that you think something a leaf tensor but actually it isn’t. And this usually happens if you perform operations on a Tensor that requires gradients.

For example, in your case,

```
x = torch.ones(1, requires_grad=True) # x is a leaf tensor
x = x.double() # x is not a leaf tensor
```

With the second statement, `x` is no longer a leaf because it is the result of the `.double()` operation.